# Is there a way to select in one click this-my-own-text?

Tags: select, text, keyboard-shortcuts

Suppose I have :

> this_my_own_text

with double left-click on my mouse, I can select the whole text. But, if the text is :

> this-my-own-text

I can select only a word, the one where the mouse is over, which is very boring working (for example) on CSS classes name (`.container-div-father`).

Is there a way (on Windows) to select all text when there is the `-` seperator? Maybe with some other key?

Comment: What does this inherently have to do with CSS?

Comment: Just an example, working on it...

Comment: I would also love an answer to this. It has to do with CSS because, I, at least, much prefer dashes to underscores, and it saves a lot of time to double click compared to selecting the start and end of a class/id.

Comment: @Chords: That does not make it a CSS question.

Comment: You asked what it has to do with CSS. Bask in the glory of it's connection. I'm not talking about if it should be tagged, just answering you, pal ;)

Comment: My Eclipse selects the whole class-name on double-click, even with normal dashes. ;)

Comment: @Yoshi : you are lucky :) On visual studio with double click it is not possible...

Comment: Mouse button down, drag, release mouse button. One click.

Comment: Lol...that's annoying @MetalFrog :)

Answer (score 0):

I could think of two ways: Triple click with the left mouse button - that'll select the whole paragraph - or click at the beginning of the text you want to select, hold down the Shift button, and then click at the end of the text you wish to select. The latter approach will also let you start and end selection in the middle of the word.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't really answer the question. If you have "test-class" it captures the quotes as well, and you might as well just click and drag as opposed to shift.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's true. It's the only thing I could think of, though.

Comment: I'm thinking there must be some kind of override in Sublime Text 2 but I'm not very familiar with settings for it.

Comment: I'm quite sure we can do it :)